# Decode Japanese character of file name when unzip

Tags: python, decode, cjk

I decode a file name :

> 20180126/\x83\x8a\x83/\x81[\x83X\x83f\x81[\x83^\x8d\xb7\x82\xb5\x91\xd6\x82\xa6\x8a\xd6\x98A\x8e\x91\x97\xbf/

using Python. But it give error with \x83/\x81 character.

> codec can't decode bytes in position 11-12: illegal multibyte sequence

This is sample code :

```
uf = codecs.decode(bad_filename, 'shift_jisx0213')
```

I've try using these codec : 'shift_jisx0213', 'cp932'

How can I fix this? Is there any programming language or library can decode this?

Comment: Removing the forward-slash between the third and the fourth hex escape, I managed to decode the file name from SJIS:
perl -e 'print "20180126/\x83\x8a\x83\x81[\x83X\x83f\x81[\x83^\x8d\xb7\x82\xb5\x91\xd6\x82\xa6\x8a\xd6\x98A\x8e\x91\x97\xbf/"' | iconv -f SJIS -t UTF8
20180126/リメ[スデータ差し替え関連資料/

Comment: It's simply a mistake to use sjisx0213 for Windows related files. Just use cp932. Some kanjis (髙, etc) translate differently in sjisx0213.

Answer (score 4):

There is a forward-slash that does not belong between the third and the fourth hex escape. Remove this slash and things work just fine:

```
>>> print(b"20180126/\x83\x8a\x83\x81[\x83X\x83f\x81[\x83^\x8d\xb7\x82\xb5"
        b"\x91\xd6\x82\xa6\x8a\xd6\x98A\x8e\x91\x97\xbf/".decode("shift_jisx0213"))
20180126/リメ[スデータ差し替え関連資料/
```

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  Error given : File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: character maps to <undefined>
Have any problem in my python?

Comment: @quangkid Likely a typo instead of a defective Python. Can you create a repl ([like this](https://repl.it/@phihag/decodejapanese)) of your complete code that exhibits the problem? When you copy the entire code from [that repl](https://repl.it/@phihag/decodejapanese), does it work on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not type. Just copy and enter :). This is result : https://imgur.com/a/ItrBU

Comment: The error you gave appears to occur in the `encode` phase of `cp437`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 This code page does not have Japanese characters. This is a bit of a Windows console problem. I recommend outputting to a file instead. But if you need this on your Windows console, this package may help: https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console